# Curl command to select and insert the data (document) into the Couchbase bucket using cmd

Tags: rest, curl, couchbase

I am trying to just select the bucket from Couchbase, I am unable to do so As I am following the link below which does not contain adequate and basic information. And there after I want to insert the document into the bucket as well using simple curl command. I tried using material avaiable on google but it wont help me on that. Please help me out to make simple select and Insert query for same..Thank you in advance

curl -v http://localhost:8091/query/service -d 'statement=SELECT `Emp Id` FROM Employee WHERE META().id ="01"'

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/curl.html

Bucket contains data as -

[image]

Comment: That docs link is for using CURL *within* your N1QL query. As there are many tools for making HTTP requests beyond just CURL, what you probably should google for (in general, not just for Couchbase) is "REST" or "HTTP" - and you would land on something like this: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Checkout query service [REST API](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uyv4t06DNGq7TxJjGI_T_MbbEYf8Er-imC7yzTY0uZw/edit#heading=h.lfqenz86v2rl)  (docs link: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html)

Also CURL must send request to query service port (8093), OR use couchbase SDKs

```
curl -v -u user:pass http://localhost:8093/query/service -d 'statement=SELECT `Emp Id` FROM Employee USE KEYS "Emp Id:01"'
curl -v -u user:pass http://localhost:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"statement":"SELECT `Emp Id` FROM Employee USE KEYS \"Emp Id:01\""}'
```